# CropBox and MediaBox in GhostScript

Tags: ghostscript

I'm using Ghostscript to turn PDFs into jpeg thumbnails. It works great for most files, but I've got a few that end up looking bad - like a tiny thumbnail on a huge white background.

This is because, on those problem PDFs, the MediaBox is set to a much larger size than the CropBox. I can fix this in Ghostscript by using -dUseCropbox to make it ignore the MediaBox dimensions ... but that does not work on other PDFs that have no CropBox defined.

So I can think of two solutions:

1. Somehow check a PDF file before import to see whether it has a CropBox defined. If it has a CropBox, then use the -dUseCropBox switch. If it does not have a CropBox defined, then we do not use that switch.
2. Modifying the MediaBox dimensions in the PDF file itself so that they match the CropBox dimensions.

So what code would I use to check a PDF file for CropBox/MediaBox dimensions and, if necessary, edit them?

Answer (score 1):

What do you plan to do with files that have no CropBox ? It seems to me that you are already doing everything you can, if a CropBox is present (and you select -dUseCropBox) it is used, if not then (if I recall correctly) GS will use the MediaBox anyway.

Comment: No, the problem is that -dUseCropBox doesn't revert to a mediabox when a cropbox doesn't exist. It only process the files with a cropbox defined and skips the ones without a cropbox.

Comment: In other words, I want it to use the cropbox if it exists and the mediabox if it doesn't. It would make sense if -dUseCropBox worked that way, but it doesn't. It only works on files with cropboxes defined and doesn't default to the mediabox like I wish it would when the cropbox doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're really looking for is a program / script to crop whitespace from PDFs, irrespective of the media/trim/crop box setting, you could try either of these freeware pdf croppers:

pdfcrop - a perl script, works on multiple platforms
http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/pdfcrop
(requires *tex, ghostscript and obviously perl)

PDF Cropper, for Windows
http://www.noliturbare.com/pdf-tools/pdf-cropper
(requires ghostscript and .NET 3.5)

Alternatively, if you have a Mac, you could use the crop function on the Preview application. This sets the cropbox without touching the mediabox (at least it does on MacOSX 10.4), allowing you to use -dUseCropbox.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Ghostscript, use Imagemagick. For example:

```
convert -resize 70px file.pdf file.jpg
```

Comment: This will rasterize the PDF, which may not be what you want in some situations.

Comment: Yes, but the description of the question states wanting to create JPG thumbnails. Perhaps the title should be edited to clarify.